# Calling method via Ajax in Struts 1

Tags: ajax, struts-1

I have action class that derive from DispatchAction. I want to call a method from in there using ajax. When I click the button that is shown below, I want to go InvitationAction's add method.
Fault is "Request[/InvitationAction] does not contain handler parameter named method."
Thanks in advance.

```
public class InvitationAction extends DispatchAction{

public ActionForward add(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, 
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    InvitationForm invForm = (InvitationForm)form;
    Person newPerson = new Person();
    newPerson.setFirstName(invForm.getFirstName());
    newPerson.setLastName(invForm.getLastName());
    invForm.getPersonMap().put(invForm.getKey(), newPerson);
    invForm.reset(mapping, request);
    return mapping.findForward("success");
}

public ActionForward delete(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, 
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    InvitationForm invForm = (InvitationForm)form;
    invForm.getPersonMap().remove(invForm.getKey());
    return mapping.findForward("success");
}

public ActionForward edit(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, 
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    InvitationForm invForm = (InvitationForm)form;
    Person person = invForm.getPersonMap().get(invForm.getKey());
    invForm.setFirstName(person.getFirstName());
    invForm.setLastName(person.getLastName());
    return mapping.findForward("success");
}
```

}

.jsp side

```
function doAjaxPost() {  

  $.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "/AjaxWithStruts1/InvitationAction.do?action=edit",
    success: function(response){  
      // we have the response  
      $('#info').html(response);  
    },  
    error: function(e){  
      alert('Error: ' + e);  

    }  
  });  
}  

<input type="button" value="add" onclick="doAjaxPost()"><br/>
```

struts-config.xml side

```
<action-mappings>

    <action name="invitationForm" path="/invitation" type="com.raistudies.actions.InvitationAction" 
    scope="session" input="/index.jsp" parameter="action">
        <forward name="success" path="/index.jsp" redirect="true"/>
    </action>

</action-mappings>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. Struts doesn't care if a request is Ajax or not; just make the Ajax request to the action with the same URL you would from the browser's URL bar.

Comment: I have tried what you said, but I faced error that is named error[object XMLHttpRequest]. Why is that ?

Comment: You'd need to describe what's happening, how, and when, if you want someone to answer that question. You don't even show how you're making the request--but so far it looks like either a JS issue, or a server error that's making it back to JS and the JS doesn't handle it properly.

Comment: Sorry about that. I have done some editing in questions.

Comment: So what's the error? Log it, expand it. Check the wire to see what's in the response. Check the server/error logs. You need to debug it; we can't see what's happening.

Comment: org.apache.struts.chain.commands.InvalidPathException: No action config found for the specified url. I have taken this fault.

Comment: So, check the full URL being requested in the network tab. See if you can call the same one from the browser bar. If you can, then see if there's something in your stack that's doing something funky with XHTTP requests. If you can't, fix your Struts config.

Comment: I have faced same error. I will try looking stack.

Comment: Hi, I am working in similar project, I think I can help you in this regard, but there are many things that are not clear in your question. For example where is your AjaxSubmit.java class? In the doAjaxPost method, does that response object means the responseText or just the response object? And you should also check what does your unspecified AjaxSubmit class submit? The best is to include all of your existing codes!

Comment: Hi Neo182, I have made mistake now I correct them up to me. Hence, I have already access related function on  DispatchAction. I take Request[/InvitationAction ] does not contain handler parameter named method fault.

Answer (score 0):

For Dispatch Action use URL in ajax call you need to specify path (**/invitation.do**) of mapping instead of action (**/InvitationAction.do**).

```
function doAjaxPost() {  
  $.ajax({  
   type: "POST",  
   url: "/AjaxWithStruts1/invitation.do?action=edit",
   success: function(response){  
   // we have the response  
   $('#info').html(response);  
 },  
  error: function(e){  
   alert('Error: ' + e);  

 }  
 });  
}
```

And in mapping give validation as FALSE

```
<action name="invitationForm" path="/invitation" type="com.raistudies.actions.InvitationAction" 
   scope="session" input="/index.jsp" parameter="action" validation="false">
    <forward name="success" path="/index.jsp" redirect="true"/>
</action>
```